# Want to install Lutron Occupancy Sensor, but confused on current switch wiring

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch

This is the original wiring, once I saw it I decided to not touch it. I don't know enough about this to make guesses. I know the bare/green from new switch would wirenut tie to the existing bare, but am at a loss how to handle the other 3 connections.

This is a single pole, controls light at top of garage ceiling. There are several other power outlets in the garage, which I'm guessing this acts as a sort of pass through?

[image: This is the original wiring]

This is the new light switch/sensor.

[image]

Comment: BTW, big props for NOT taking everything apart before asking for help!

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the junction box please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a [MS-OPS2H-WH](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-2-Amp-Single-Pole-Motion-Sensor-Switch-White-MS-OPS2H-WH/203202128).
It doesn't require neutral so the wiring it simple.

For the two back wires that currently go to one terminal on the old switch, use a wire connector and twist those together with one of the black wires from the occupancy sensor (*does not matter which one*).

Connect the other black wire from the other old switch terminal to the remaining black wire from the new occupancy sensor.

Connect the green wire with the bare copper wire in the box.

Comment: appears to have done the trick. I can toggle it on and off and doesn't seem to affect the other outlets. Thanks! As an aside, is there any good places to learn more about common household wiring to better understand these oddball configurations?

Comment: youtube has tons of common wiring instructional videos. sparky channel is good.